# How do you know when the asker has read your answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers

Sometimes when I write a pretty long answer I never know whether he/she has read my answer or had just left and decided not to bother with it.
I don't however want to know everyone who has read it however maybe like a small green icon that says read or something

So is this already possible and if not it should be

*Note I am using mobile version of Stack Exchange so I apologise if it is already on desktop version*

Comment: If you assume that the OP is interested in responses and checks the thread when alerted to a new posting, you could look at their "last seen" time on their profile page (click their username under their post).  If they haven't been seen since before you posted your answer, then they haven't seen it.  If they have been seen since you posted it, there's a good chance they looked at it, but not a guarantee.  Keep in mind that even when the OP responds in some way, it often isn't immediate.  They may need to test your answer, and that might not be possible the same day.

Comment: While an answer should be written to answer the the question, your answer should be written in such a way, anyone else with the same problem is helped.  In other words the purpose of Superuser is to get answers to questions, there is not shortage of questions, good quality answers are hard to come by.